# Generating meaningful sample data in R based on conditions?

Tags: r, modeling

I'm trying to generate some sample insurance claims data that is meaningful instead of just random numbers.

Assuming I have two columns Age and Injury, I need meaningful values for ClaimAmount based on certain conditions:

```
ClaimantAge | InjuryType | ClaimAmount
---------------------------------------
    35        Bruises
    55        Fractures
    .            .
    .            .
    .            .
```

1. I want to generate claim amounts that increase as age increases, and then plateaus at around a certain age, say 65.
2. Claims for certain injuries need to be higher than claims for other types of injuries.

Currently I am generating my samples in a random manner, like so:

```
amount <- sample(0:100000, 2000, replace = TRUE)
```

How do I generate more meaningful samples?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but maybe think in terms of distributions, and then generate samples in based of your distributions. In my case normal distribution did the work but here is a sample of all the dist and their functions: http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/old/5101/rlook.html#dist

Comment: @oscartorom Thanks for your reply. I am going through the link now. I have edited my question for more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways that this could need to be adjusted, as I don't know the field. Given that we're talking about dollar amounts, I would use the poisson distribution to generate data.

```
set.seed(1)
n_claims <- 2000
injuries <- c("bruises", "fractures")
prob_injuries <- c(0.7, 0.3)

sim_claims <- data.frame(claimid = 1:n_claims)
sim_claims$age <- round(rnorm(n = n_claims, mean = 35, sd = 15), 0)
sim_claims$Injury <- factor(sample(injuries, size = n_claims, replace = TRUE, prob = prob_injuries))
sim_claims$Amount <- rpois(n_claims, lambda = 100 + (5 * (sim_claims$age - median(sim_claims$age))) + 
                             dplyr::case_when(sim_claims$Injury == "bruises" ~ 50,
                                              sim_claims$Injury == "fractures" ~ 500))

head(sim_claims)

  claimid age    Injury Amount
1       1  26   bruises    117
2       2  38   bruises    175
3       3  22   bruises    102
4       4  59   bruises    261
5       5  40 fractures    644
6       6  23   bruises     92
```

Comment: You can't, because the mean and the variance are the same in a poisson distribution. You'd have to use the negative binomial distribution instead. The R function is `rnbinom()`, which allows for different variance.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer has helped.